# Best course of action to 50+ databases with over 100+ tables/views

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado

I've been tasked with making a web application that will display certain data from multiple databases/tables/views. I currently have been learning ASP MVC 5 to display data and I've been able to successfully connect to a database and display the information needed using Entity Framework 6. However, my issue is that this will become very tedious to continue doing this for multiple databases/tables/views even using scaffolding.

My current thought process is to go about making dynamic views/controllers or even have a way of programmatically creating views/controllers. I don't know if there is a way for me to create entity framework models at run time? I also don't know if there is better solutions out there to do something like this.

Follow up question, is it better to just use ADO .NET to access all this information? Or is there a way for me to just create a connection string and a new dbcontext/entity and then just connect to it that way without needing to generate the whole model?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have so many databases and tables?  Are you creating them as a part of the application?

Comment: My company is wanting an application that will allow us to view all our employees + see what access they have in certain applications. This will allow us to audit our employees access better

Comment: It sounds like your external model (the one end users work with) is far simpler than the internal data, which does not need full metadata modeling. Consider using a more dynamic ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), especially if you're only reading data. There is no requirement that views and controllers are in a 1-to-1 correspondence with the database via EF, and in this case it definitely sounds like they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use Webforms and ASP.NET Dynamic Data, it will scaffold an entire database for you instead of scaffolding each controller one by one.

You can see more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.aspx